# Android front and rear camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I need know how to record videos from the front camera and the rear camera at the same time on Android devices (into different files). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some sort of application out there for this. I will do some research and if I find it I will edit this post with a link to the application!

Edit: Found it! Try an application called EyeReport!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but so far, only with the upcoming Samsung Galaxy S4.

It has a dual-camera feature but who knows whether it's hardware-dependant or a software-modification by Samsung, at this stage.

Hopefully it can be ported to other phones, if it's just software.

There are apps out there that switch between front and back every 0.01sec but they dont work well at all and it does depend on the phone speed then aswell